# JQUERY de ONCLIK para IFRAME não funciona

Tags: jquery, iframe

Faço banners animados no  Google Web Designer e uso um IFRAME para chamar eles na pagina, usei um código JQUERY para que quando clicado em cima do IFRAME ele abrisse outra pagina mas quando adiciono 2 ou 3 bannes, tendo cada um seu site proprio para abrir e funções com o nome diferente, só funciona um banner, os outros ficam sem a função ONCLICK.

o codigo que usei é esse:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var oFrame = document.getElementById("FrameLateral");

    oFrame.contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {

    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/events/291519031247073/', '_blank');

    };

};

window.onload = function() {

    var oFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");

    oFrame.contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {

    window.open(' SITE ', '_blank');

    };

};
```

E no caso esse seria o IFRAME:

```
<center><iframe id="myframe" class="asd" src="http://127.0.0.1/CSS/animation/matanzafoz/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></center><br>
```

e em outro IFRAME:

```
    <center><iframe id="FrameLateral" class="asd" src="http://127.0.0.1/CSS/animation/novobanner/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></center><br>
```